# Rational Functional Tester Finding Missing Dynamic Object-

Tags: java, rft

RFT- I am currently working with RFT to automate a dynamic test object web application.  I recorded a page, but instead of mapping specific objects it maps it to HTML.Browser, Such as a list of radio buttons that cannot be recognized when I inspect an element because they are nested within HTML.Browser instead of Html.INPUT.radio, what can I do to overcome this?  I am new to automation so I hope I explained this correctly.

Comment: I was able to find the missing object, but how do I insert the missing object into my test script using the find ()-